# Could not load file or asssembly 'Microsoft.identity.client'

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, github-copilot

I want to install Github Copilot extension in Visual studio 2022. when i install it, i close all vs 2022 as instructed then i am supposed to receive a message saying that it was done.

However i keep getting an error from VSIX Installer saying:

Could not load file or asssembly 'Microsoft.identity.client, version=4.30.0.0,culture=neutral,PublickeyToken=0a613f4dd989eBae' or one of its dependencies. the located assembly's manifest definition does not match the asssembly reference.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x801311040).

I get the same message when i try to update any extensions i have in visual studio 2022

PS: I already installed Copilot in VsCode and it working perfectly.

Thank you!

Comment: I can install this extension in visual studio without any error. What's the version of your visual studio 2022? Maybe you can try to repair visual studio in visual studio installer and try again.

Comment: From where can I check the version of vs 2022?

Comment: It did not work, I still get the same message.

Comment: You can check the version of vs2022 from Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio in visual studio or check it in visual studio installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It FINALLY worked. The error happened because I didn't have app installer and Microsoft store so I had to reset my windows 10 then the problem was solved.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! You can click '✔' to accept your answer. See [can I answer my own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I can't just go reset everything. Can you elaborate a bit more on what was missing / had to be reset? I have app installer and Microsoft store.

Comment: Well appart from resetting Windows 10, my visual studio app also needed an updated. That's it. I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in from a clean state:

1. Close Visual Studio 2022.
2. Delete C:\Users\AppData\Local\github-copilot\hosts.json
3. Log out of GitHub in the web browser.
4. Open Visual Studio.